# saved bitmap is larger than the bitmap i read C#

Tags: c#, bitmap

Actually the bitmap created has a file size larger than the input bitmap. I opened the bitmap that was created and it looked completely different to what i inputted. why is that ?

I read a bitmap through FileStream and then i write its contents to a bitmap object.Next i write it as a bitmap file onto harddisk. I cant figure out why the output bitmap is larger than the input bitmap. Could someone please help me.

Comment: I think that, by default, c# will convert to png. I may be wrong

Comment: yup its png. Doesnt the png format compress the image ?

Comment: The bitmap isn't saved in the BMP format, it will be a PNG since you didn't specify the ImageFormat.  And you didn't specify the full path of the file so it may end up in a directory you didn't expect.  Environment.CurrentDirectory.  I suspect that is at least part of the confusion.

Comment: @user581544 although png is normally compressed using flate, for some data, the compressed size can actually be larger

Answer (score 2):

[Bitmap.Save (Image.Save)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ktx83wah.aspx) will, by default, save the image as in PNG format.

If you call [Save with an ImageFormat value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142147.aspx), you should get your bitmap.

```
b.Save("test.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

Comment: hi i updated my question. I read bitmap as a FileStream and then i create a bitmap object and write the file that i read onto bitmap object. Next i save the bitmap object as a bitmap file. In this process the file that i read is not equal to the file that is written.

Comment: Well, bmp format is pretty straightforward, but things like optional information headers may change.

Answer (score 2):

When a bitmap file is created there is often padding added to each row to ensure that each row is a multiple of 4 bytes. When you read the bitmap file into a FileStream the padding is also read.

This can mean that the FileStream is larger than expected and when you write it to a bitmap it will display unexpected behaviour since when you write it to a new Bitmap it treats the padding as if it were your image data.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I did not understand your problem well. But did you try like this?

```
private System.Drawing.Bitmap readfromFile(string filename)
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        byte[] bytes = new byte[fs.Length];
        fs.Read(bytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
        System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(ms);
        return bmp;
    }
```

and saved like this:

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp = readfromFile("xxxx --- Path");
                bmp.Save("test.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

I tried that and it always returns the same image for me.